# Erase NA's from Datasets

Tags: r, na

Im working and preparing 4 datasets which are called GEM, GLOBE, Hofstede and GPS. They have been shown below:

```
> new_GemData<-lapply(GemData, head)
> dput(head(new_GemData))
list(cntry = c(".", "ABW", "AFG", "AGO", "AIA", "ALB"), all_tea = c(6.2942258871149, 
NA, NA, 26.1555808326023, NA, NA), all_nes_entre = c(1.88915438310442, 
NA, NA, 7.6296866239702, NA, NA), all_opp_entre = c(4.32969440907848, 
NA, NA, 17.1323566956254, NA, NA), all_tea_male_entre = c(8.96311504196867, 
NA, NA, 26.9322388085985, NA, NA), all_tea_female_entre = c(3.53006299869866, 
NA, NA, 25.5152945703973, NA, NA))
> new_GlobeData<-lapply(GlobeData, head)
> dput(head(new_GlobeData))
list(Country = c(2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8), `Country Name` = c("United Kingdom", 
"Costa Rica", "Italy", "India", "Namibia", "Czech Republic"), 
    `Uncertainty Avoidance Societal Practices` = c(4.65123456790123, 
    3.82456140350877, 3.78755868544601, 4.1504854368932, 4.2, 
    4.43958333333333), `Future Orientation Societal Practices` = c(4.27901234567901, 
    3.60350877192982, 3.25258215962441, 4.19271844660194, 3.49333333333333, 
    3.63041666666667), `Power Distance Societal Practices` = c(5.15308641975309, 
    4.73684210526316, 5.4268779342723, 5.46601941747573, 5.29333333333333, 
    3.58875), `Collectivism I Societal Practices Institutional Collectivism` = c(4.27160493827161, 
    3.92982456140351, 3.67899061032864, 4.38106796116505, 4.13333333333333, 
    3.60486111111111))
> new_Hofstede<-lapply(Hofstede, head)
> dput(head(new_Hofstede))
list(ctr = c("ALB", "ALG", "AND", "ARE", "ARG", "ARM"), country = c("Albania", 
"Algeria", "Andorra", "United Arab Emirates", "Argentina", "Armenia"
), `Power Distance` = c(".", ".", ".", "80", "49", "."), Individualism = c(".", 
".", ".", "38", "46", "."), Masculinity = c(".", ".", ".", "53", 
"56", "."), `Uncertainty Avoidance` = c(".", ".", ".", "68", 
"86", "."))
> new_GpsData<-lapply(GpsData, head)
> dput(head(new_GpsData))
list(country = c("Afghanistan", "Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia", 
"Austria", "Bangladesh"), isocode = c("AFG", "DZA", "ARG", "AUS", 
"AUT", "BGD"), patience = c(-0.201360121369362, 0.0598152466118336, 
-0.229307979345322, 0.65700376033783, 0.608285009860992, 0.0811367109417915
), risktaking = c(0.120764262974262, 0.391530483961105, 0.0415031686425209, 
0.137136548757553, -0.0618291534483433, -0.198067754507065), 
    posrecip = c(0.2896409034729, -0.598255336284637, 0.159679308533669, 
    0.069660022854805, 0.161046594381332, 0.154367566108704), 
    negrecip = c(0.254712462425232, 0.254900813102722, -0.140457272529602, 
    0.0221897512674332, -0.0554154515266418, 0.113288171589375
    ))
```

Im struggling to **find the missing values/NA and then erase them from each dataset**, thats why because the NA's create me problems in some regressions i would like to run.

Comment: Read about `complete.cases`.

Comment: `na.omit` can help you